# Weblogic redirection error

Tags: dns, ip, weblogic

I am currently facing a problem in Weblogic with respect to DNS.

Scenario: The user accesses the portal by DNS "www.xxxx.com.br" and when he logs in he is redirected to the IP "10.18.x.70:7010/Portal", where the application is being deployed on the Weblogic server.

It is noteworthy that there is no forced redirection or failed redirection in the application code.

I would like help to understand this behavior.

Comment: Hi @Lucas - it's not clear from the question what the problem is - and please ask the question / clarify in english (as is required on these sites).

Comment: My crystal ball says: your application issues a redirect based on where it sees itself running. Often there's a config setting for the "URL of the app", which you should set to your `https://www.xxxx.com.br` or something along those lines. I'm not familiar with Weblogic, so this is as specific as I can get.